# ggplot colors correct on legend, wrong on plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

The legend looks right, but the last two plotted `geom_line` curves (e.x and ten.x) are grayed-out on the plot.

How to fix?

[image: plot with incorrect colors][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MrOA.png)

```
Xp <- 1:20/5
X <- -10:10/5
X10 <- -10:5/5

df <- data.frame(
    x = Xp, 
    log2.x. = log2(Xp),
    log.x. = log(Xp),
    log10.x. = log10(Xp)) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(
    x = X,
    two.x = 2 ** X,
    e.x = exp(X))) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(
    x = X10,
    ten.x = 10 ** X10)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(x), names_to = "transformation") %>%
  mutate(name = factor(transformation, levels = unique(transformation)))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value, color=transformation)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "log2.x." = "red",
    "log.x" = "green",
    "log10.x" = "blue",
    "two.x" = "red",
    "e.x" = "green",
    "ten.x" = "blue"))
```

Comment: Minor typos: change "log.x" to "log.x." and "log10.x" to "log10.x." (i.e. full stops at the end")

Comment: wow the minor typo caused the problem!  funny how it showed up three plots later on the e.x and 10.x, even though the typos were on the log.x and the log10.x ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. makes pretty mad sometimes :D

```
df%>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value, color=transformation)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "log2.x." = "red",
    "log.x." = "green",
    "log10.x." = "blue",
    "two.x" = "red",
    "e.x" = "green",
    "ten.x" = "blue"))
```

[image: colored]